# Endless loop in a Facebook game with Firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox

I have a game in Facebook and suddenly a new problem came out. In Chrome, Safari, Opera and Internet Explorer work fine. In Firefox the Facebook page loads good but when the game iframe starts loading, it gets a points that automatically reload the whole page. I can not understand what's happening. Anyone could know the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is good know problem for me, about half year ago I got the same also with Firefox. In my app real problem was that, firefox with his `AJAX` action, lost somewhere access token from parent window/frame...

My advice: try to stick access token to `AJAX`'s request too.

**Edit in response to comment:**

Unfortunatelly, now I can't see any token in `url` into my app frame... but what I did then was something like that: (using `jQuery`):

`$.get("http://mydomain/getInfo?id=12345 + '&' + (location.href.split('?'))[1])`

where `location.href.split('?'))[1]` add session/access token to my intern `AJAX` request.

Anyway, if application works fine few days ago, check official facebook dev forum, there is often some cause on facebook side...

Comment: Hi Rin, thanks for your answer. Could you please explain it to me a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either accept third party cookies or locate the one cookie it needs to load (seems to be the developers's own website usually - look into the list of cookies currently stored on your computer in ff options) and whitelist(allow) that.

Since that answer is nowhere on the net and I just spent one hour trying to figure it out to fix the same problem I'm putting it here in the hope it'll help.